# How to define baseclass or interface for constants?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

In my application, I need to define a same set of Constant values for multiple classes and I want to use one baseclass/interface of all them as type param to my generic class.

```
//I know following code will not work, just trying to demonstrate the problem
public interface IConstantsDefined
{
    static const string DbName;
    static const string TableName;
    static const string ColumnName;
}

public static class Product : IConstantsDefined
{
    public static const string DbName = "ProductDB";
    public static const string TableName = "Products";
    public static const string ColumnName = "ProductId";
}

public static class Sales: IConstantsDefined
{
    public static const string DbName = "SalesDb";
    public static const string TableName = "Sales";
    public static const string ColumnName = "SaleId";
}

public class DbConnection<TConsts> where TConsts : IConstantsDefined
{
// use TConsts.DbName, TConsts.TableName here
}
```

I understand that what I wrote above will throw many errors in C#. I know that static class can not inherit from interface. Question I have is, what is the best design/approach to build such a system, keeping performance and memory in mind?

Comment: You could try an abstract class with properties (fields are not allowed as ab stract). Getter only, with your "const" values.

Comment: use constants with care. They are compiled into the assembly verbatim so if they are in a library, and they change, referencing code must be recompiled.

Comment: When you face request "inherit static member" - you are probably doing something wrong already. Otherwise, abstract class with abstract property (which will be implemented differently) is the way.

Comment: All my Product or Sales class would have is various constants, so I do not want to create instance of these. Therefore I want to use these constants as static members of class. That's why I was trying to avoid abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are defined and initialized once.

```
public interface IConstantsDefined
{
    static const string Foo = "Foo";
    static const string Bar = "Bar";
}
```

What you want are abstract get-only fields:

```
public interface IConstantsDefined
{
    string DbName { get };
    string TableName { get };
    string ColumnName { get };
}

public class Product : IConstantsDefined
{
    public string DbName { get { return "ProductDB" } };
    public string TableName { get { return "Products" } };
    public string ColumnName { get { return "ProductId" } };
}

public class Sales: IConstantsDefined
{
    public string DbName { get { return "ProductDB" } };
    public string TableName { get { return "Sales" } };
    public string ColumnName { get { return "SaleId" } };
}
```

Since you don't need/want multiple instances of the Product and Sales types you might want to consider dropping the types altogether as this is pretty much the definition of a class:

```
public class ConstantsDefined
{
    public string DbName { get; private set; };
    public string TableName { get; private set; };
    public string ColumnName { get; private set; };

    public static readonly ConstantsDefined Product = new ConstantsDefined()
    {
        DbName = "ProductDB",
        TableName = "Products",
        ColumnName = "ProductId",
    };
}
```

Comment: @Sinatr That was an oversight. I meant to post them as normal classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as in the comment from @nabuchodonossor. Or, you can create Metadata classes, ProductMetadata and SalesMetadata which implement interface IMetadata. Then when needed, you could use a factory to get metadata instance by passing in the actual Model information(typeof(Sales) for example).

Comment: I guess the answer from @Kempeth would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

The closest one to achieve wanted is this, using base abstract class:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract string DbName { get; }
}
class Product : Base
{
    public override string DbName => "ProductDB";
}
class Sales : Base
{
    public override string DbName => "SalesDB";
}
class DbConnection<T> where T : Base
{
    public string Test(T instance) => instance.DbName;
}
```

This indeed require `instance`, which can be hold by `DbConnection`, resolved by service provider, etc.

> All my Product or Sales class would have is various constants, so I do not want to create instance of these

This requirement basically change everything. It seems you understand *constant* in given context as "a value which can't be changed". Which is *immutable* type. Then you do not need generics to construct type with constants, simply *pass parameters* (as you would do with any immutable type):

```
class DbConnection
{
    public string DbName { get; }

    public DbConnection(string dbName)
    {
        DbName = dbName;
    }
}
```

Usage: instead of mysterious `new DbConnection<Product>()` you simply do `new DbConnection("ProductDB")`. If you have multiple parameters, then consider to wrap those and pass instance to constructor. And this is where you end up with abstract class and non-static inheritance as in my first snippet: `new DbConnection(new Product())` (while `DbConnection` will require `Base` type to pass).